# How to detect a button pressed in Shiny modules in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am stuck about how to know whether a button inside a Shiny module is pressed. In this simplified example below, I created a module (`buttonUI`, `buttonServer`): there is a button inside this module, and my goal is to "know" (detect) this button is pressed from outside of the module.

```
buttonUI <- function(id) {

  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(actionButton(ns("btn"), "a button label")
  )}

buttonServer <- function(id, parent) {
  moduleServer(id,
               ## Below is the module function
               function(input, output, session) {
                 
                 ns <- session$ns
                 ret <- reactiveVal(0)
                 observeEvent(input$btn,{
                   message("inner", ret())
                   ret(ret()+1)
                 })
                 
                   list(n = reactive(ret))
               })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  buttonUI("mod")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  v = buttonServer("mod")
  observeEvent(v$n, {
    message("outer")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I expected to see many outputs of "outer" when I clicked the button, but I do not see any.

PS: I have tried to return a single reactive value (`return(ret)`) instead of a list (e.g., `list(n = reactive(ret))`). I found `return(ret)` will work, but do not know why it works. However, I need the module to return a list instead of a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trick to pass values from outside to inside shiny module and from inside to outside. It consists in using reactiveValues : you initialise a reactiveValues in your server, you pass it as an argument in you server module, and it is changed inside the module AND outside the module.
You can check [this page](https://rtask.thinkr.fr/communication-between-modules-and-its-whims/) for more examples.

PS: reactiveValues is a list, so you can pass as much variables as you want inside/ outstide your module(s)

```
buttonUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(actionButton(ns("btn"), "a button label")
)}

buttonServer <- function(id, parent, rv) { #rv is an argument
  moduleServer(id,
   ## Below is the module function
   function(input, output, session) {
     
     ns <- session$ns
     ret <- reactiveVal(0)
     observeEvent(input$btn,{
       rv$btn <- input$btn #increment rv
       message("rv_inner", rv$btn)
       message("inner", ret())
       ret(ret()+1)
     })
     
     list(n = reactive(ret)) # no need to return rv
   })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  buttonUI("mod")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(btn = NULL) # initialise reactiveValues
  
  v = buttonServer("mod", rv = rv) # pass reactiveValues as argument
  observeEvent(v$n, {
    message("outer")
  })
  observeEvent(rv$btn, { #check rv$btn value
    message("rv_outer", rv$btn)
  })
 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You can do the same thing with `session$userData`, which is shared by both modules and the main server function.

Comment: @Limey thanks, `session$userData` can be very helpful.

Comment: @gdevaux thanks for the solution. The link you provided is fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Here I used a simple trick.
As stated before, you can return a reactive value from a moduleServer and use that value to determine if the button was pressed

In my case, I used an eventReactive() so you can tie a reactive value directly to the actions related to the button

```
library(shiny)

buttonUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  actionButton(ns("btn"), "a button label")
}

buttonServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    isPressed <- eventReactive(input$btn, {
      if(input$btn){
        "The button was pressed"
      } else {
        "The button was NOT pressed"
      }
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    return(isPressed())
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  buttonUI("mod"),
  textOutput("text")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    buttonServer("mod")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case (as the question said), I will need the module to return a list instead of one reactive value.